# new operator overloading in c++

Tags: c++

I know that in C++ we can overload new and delete operator. But, I have a question regarding how that call to overloaded operator new is made. There are two things:

1. if I have static overloaded new like this

   ```
   static void* operator new(size_t size)
   {
      std::cout << "new called";
      return nullptr;
   }
   ```

   I can call

   ```
   Test* t = new Test();
   ```

   because I understand that I don't need to create an object to call the overloaded new. I can first call the new operator and then the constructor after that.
2. However, if I have this without the static like below

   ```
   class Test{
       Test(){
           std::cout << "constructed";
       }

       void* operator new(size_t size){
           std::cout << "new called";
           return nullptr;
       }
   };
   ```

   I don't understand how we can still call new operator even when the actual object hasn't been constructed. I mean how does it execute at runtime, is there something that the compiler implicitly does at compile time to make it static or what?

Comment: First question is why are you overriding `new`?

Comment: Nothing in particular, I was just reading about custom memory allocators,management and was trying out things.

Comment: You may want to look at using a custom allocator rather than overriding `new`.